# Correctness of limit proof for asymptotic analysis $ n^{\log(n)} \in o(\log(n)^n) $

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, exponential-function

Suppose that we want to show that $ n^{\log(n)} \in o(\log(n)^n) $.
Using the limit definition for asymptotic analysis we have
$$ n^{\log(n)} \in o(\log(n)^n) \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \lim_{n \to \infty } \
\frac{n^{\log(n)}}{\log(n)^n} = 0 $$
Then
\begin{align}\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{n^{\log(n)}}{\log(n)^n} &= \lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{e^{\log(n)^2} }{ e^{\log(\log(n)) n} } \\&= \lim_{n \to \infty } e^{\log(n)^2 - \log(\log(n)) n} \\&= e^{\lim_{n \to \infty } \log(n)^2 - \log(\log(n)) n} \end{align}

$$ e^{\lim_{n \to \infty } \log(n)^2 - \log(\log(n)) n} = 0 \ \Leftrightarrow \ 
\lim_{n \to \infty } \ \frac{\log(n)^2}{\log(\log(n)) n} = 0 $$

So we have

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty } \ \frac{\log(n)^2}{\log(\log(n)) n} \stackrel{\text{(L'Hopital)}}{=}   \ 2 \ \lim_{n \to \infty } \ \frac{\log(n)}{n (\frac{1}{log(n)} + log(log(n))} 
\stackrel{\text{(L'Hopital)}}{=}   \ 2 \ \lim_{n \to \infty} \ \frac{1}{n \,
(\underbrace{\frac{1}{\log(n)} + 1 + \log(\log(n)) + \frac{1}{\log(n)}}_{> \, 0} )}
= 0 $$

Is this an acceptable proof?

Comment: For $e^x$ to be $0$, one must have $x\to -\infty$. So, $e^{\lim [\cdots]}=0 \iff \lim[\cdots] = -\infty$, not $0$.

Comment: Yes. For that to hold our subtracted term $ log(log(n)) n $ has to „grow faster“ than $ \log (n)^2 $ asymptotically, which is why I transformed it to a fraction.